# FirebaseUI web single auth method

Tags: firebase, web, firebase-authentication, firebase-security, firebaseui

Let's say have a single method of authentication, let's say phone, is it possible on firebaseui web to open the authentication instead of showing a button the user has to press is in order to see the authentication.

meaning
current flow => show phone button => user presses => shows phone form
expected flow => shows phone form

thanks in advance

Jose Suero

Comment: An issue has been filed for this feature: https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/155. It should be in the works.

Comment: just commented on the issue thinking it was a coincidence someone else was looking for the same thing :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a feature request for a library on Github. It's better to simply track it there, instead of in both places.